# How can I show weeknumber in the taskbar in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, calendar

Is there a way to show the week number in the taskbar in Windows 10? I prefer it to be integrated in the Windows clock application that is showing in the taskbar anyway - directly or by left/right click. But at the moment I take any workaround including 3<sup>rd</sup> party software.

My current workaround is to open the calendar via the start menu (with week numbers enabled). So I don't need another solutions that opens a window which I manually have to close again.

**Note**: I made a second question in regards to Windows 11:
[How can I show weeknumber in the taskbar in Windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1750112/how-can-i-show-weeknumber-in-the-taskbar-in-windows-11)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [White-Tiger/T-Clock](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock). It supports Windows 10 since version 2.4.1. You can download the latest release [here](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases). Just extract then run, there's no installer

[image: T-Clock calendar]

After starting T-Clock you need to enable its calendar first right clicking on the clock > T-Clock options. In the Miscellaneous tab check on *Use T-Clock's calendar* and *Show week numbers*

[image: T-Clock options]

If you want official support please vote on [Windows 10's Feedback Hub](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/feedback-hub/9nblggh4r32n?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) (installation of the Feedback Hup App is necessary). Many people have already reported that: https://aka.ms/AA5mk4r, https://aka.ms/AA7ujey, https://aka.ms/AA7ubxo

Comment: Worked fine, I used `H:nn:ss\ndd.mm. ("W"Wi)` as formatstring, this way I get two lines: time in the top line `HH:MM:SS` and date in the bottom line `DD.MM. (W#)`. I'll gave you a +1. Haven't decided which answer should get the solution though. I tend to helpinghend since his solution doesn't require any 3rd party software, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Albin you're free to accept any answer that you like. That solution isn't free from "3rd party" software anyway as it still requires some software that's not included in Windows to compile the source code

Comment: And unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work. Since 3rd party is only a "side requirement" and you added the only working solution so far, I'll accept your answer for now.

Answer (score 6):

One option if you're really struggling, would be to create a small little application that is configured to run at startup that creates a notification tray icon.

[image: Example]

If you [download Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) 2019 Community version, you could create a new C# .Net Forms application with the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WeekCounter
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MyCustomApplicationContext());
        } 
        private static void MessageBox(string v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class MyCustomApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
    {     
        private NotifyIcon trayIcon;

        public MyCustomApplicationContext()
        {
            // Initialize Tray Icon
            trayIcon = new NotifyIcon()
            {
                Icon = WeekCounter.Properties.Resources.icon,
                Text = "WeekCounter",
                ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[] {
                new MenuItem("Exit", Exit)
            }),
                Visible = true
            };

            trayIcon.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(notifyIcon1_MouseMove);
        }
        private void notifyIcon1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            CultureInfo myCI = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            Calendar myCal = myCI.Calendar;
            CalendarWeekRule myCWR = myCI.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule;
            DayOfWeek myFirstDOW = myCI.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
            trayIcon.Text = "Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt") + "\nWeek: " + myCal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, myCWR, myFirstDOW);
        }

        void Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            trayIcon.Visible = false;
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Under the "Resources" for the project you can add a suitable ico file as an icon resource.  It is referenced in the code as "icon" so the resource will need to be named that:

```
Icon = WeekCounter.Properties.Resources.icon
```

[image: Adding icon resource]

You could ensure the exe is run at startup by adding a reference to it under the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Comment: @HelpingHand do I have to use a project template? Or can I just create an empty project and add a c#-class (into which I paste your code)?