# Show seconds in system clock in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, clock

I like to show seconds in the clock in the notification area of the taskbar (aka system tray, the lower right corner of the display).

In Windows 10, I added an item in the registry editor.

```
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

ShowSecondsInSyetemClock (DWORD 32 bit), value = 1
```

But this method does not seem to work in Windows 11.

Can I do this in Windows 11?

Comment: Try using the control panel: "To do so, open the Control Panel and go to Clock, Language, and Region. Next, click on Change date and time. Then, under Additional settings, select the Time tab. Check the box next to Show seconds in the system tray clock." - You should be able to modify the "short time" to be the same as the "long time" (i.e. `h:mm:ss tt`

Comment: @Ramhound the "show seconds" option is no longer available in Windows 11

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately at the moment with Windows 11 this can not be achieved without 3rd party software. There are several free options you can use e.g. [MantisMountainMobile/TClock-Win10](https://github.com/MantisMountainMobile/TClock-Win10) or [martinet101/ElevenClock](https://github.com/martinet101/ElevenClock/releases)  from Github.

I myself use a combination of [ExplorerPatcher](https://superuser.com/a/1713093/201818) and [White-Tiger/T-Clock](https://superuser.com/questions/1534488/how-can-i-show-weeknumber-in-the-taskbar-in-windows-10). Unfortunately, the White-Tiger branch of T-Clock does not work yet on the Windows 11 taskbar, so you need to use ExplorerPatcher to go back to the Windows 10 taskbar. I needed the ungrouping of taskbar icons so I had to go back to the Windows 10 taskbar anyway.

**Update:** I found a T-Clock branch that works on Windows 11: [MantisMountainMobile/TClock-Win10](https://github.com/MantisMountainMobile/TClock-Win10), with T-Clock you get the option to display and tweak a variety of other things like system data (CPU, mem, etc.). And it's portable so no installation is required.

Comment: Those 3rd party tools will simply restore the Windows 10 clock with some additional settings. The Windows 11 clock also has the new notification side bar linked to it for example which you will lose out on. What we want is the Windows 11 clock, with the option to enable seconds.

Comment: @ViBoNaCci that might be the case, but at the moment there is simply no implementet option to add seconds to the windows clock without using 3rd party software / replacing the clock.

Answer (score 0):

Setting ShowSecondsInSystemClock to 1 under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

works for me ✅  as of 2023 May 10 (it used to **not** work before the latest update).

[image]

My Windows is:

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎26/‎04/‎2023
OS build    22621.1702
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22641.1000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11 Version 22H2, without using the registry:

1. Right click on taskbar
2. choose "Taskbar settings"
3. scroll down to and open "Taskbar behaviors"
4. Tick "Show seconds in system tray clock"