# Display Windows 11 clock like the one in Windows 10 when tray is clicked

Tags: windows-11, clock

> Please note that this question refers to the clock when the tray is clicked, and not to the minimized tray clock like [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1750084/show-seconds-in-system-clock-in-windows-11).

**In short**:
In Windows 11, is it possible to show the clock together with the calendar, *including* the seconds part?

**Details**: When Windows 11 tray clock is clicked, the calendar is displayed ***without*** the clock:

[image]

While in Windows 10, the clock is there:

[image]

We can add a clock manually:

[image]

But I want the ***seconds*** part as in Windows 10:

[image]

I wish to ***not*** use the "show seconds" options available in Windows 11:

[image]

Comment: So are you running Windows 10 or Windows 11?

Comment: And for Windows 11 you not want to use the very option that allows you to add seconds - That option works.

Comment: The only way to enable seconds on the clock is to enable the option you don’t want to enable.

Comment: @Yisroel Tech got me spot on.

Comment: @HeyJude, there is a way to add seconds to that clock that you added on top of the Calendar (by modifying the Short Time format setting) but it won't update in Real-time, it will simply display the second count of when you opened the flyout. Would that be okay for your need? (Probably not...)

Comment: @YisroelTech not what I need :/

Comment: What you need is not available in Windows 11  - just what is offered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old taskbar calendar cannot be returned to Windows 11 except by
patching Windows components, which is a dangerous action that can force
you to reinstall Windows.
If you still wish to go this way, I suggest taking an image backup of
your disk and have a boot USB available that can reinstall this image,
for the worst case.

The YouTube post
[Get Windows 10 Calendar on Windows 11 *easy method*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMGQ5hVWFrI)
claims that installing
[ExplorerPatcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher/)
restores the taskbar to its Windows 10 version, including the calendar.

In the video, the poster demonstrated it :

[image]

ExplorerPatcher is not a product that I recommend using, and it may not
stay stable across Windows Updates.

Comment: So there is no way to get the proper clock displayed on win 11 calendar?

Comment: @DanM.: None that I know of, but I recommend to keep an eye on [Windhawk mods](https://windhawk.net/).