# How can I show weeknumber in the taskbar in Windows 11?

Tags: taskbar, windows-11, calendar

Is there a way to show the week number in the taskbar in Windows 11? I prefer it to be integrated in the Windows clock application that is showing in the taskbar anyway - directly or by left/right click.

At the moment I take any workaround including 3rd party software, preferably freeware and portable apps.

Comment: Please upvote this request in Windows feedback hub to include this feature in Window: https://aka.ms/AA5mk4r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a few workarounds, not perfect but it's a solution until something better comes along:

- A combination of [ExplorerPatcher](https://superuser.com/a/1713093/201818) and [White-Tiger/T-Clock](https://superuser.com/questions/1534488/how-can-i-show-weeknumber-in-the-taskbar-in-windows-10). Unfortunately, the White-Tiger branch of T-Clock does not work yet on the Windows 11 taskbar, so you need to use ExplorerPatcher to go back to the Windows 10 taskbar. I needed the ungrouping of taskbar icons so I had to go back to the Windows 10 taskbar anyway.
- I found a T-Clock branch that works on Windows 11: [MantisMountainMobile/TClock-Win10](https://github.com/MantisMountainMobile/TClock-Win10), unfortunately, it does not have the option to show the week number (yet)
- [martinet101/ElevenClock](https://github.com/martinet101/ElevenClock) from Github unfortunatly an installation is required.
- There is another supposed solution on GitHub: [ramensoftware/windhawk-mods](https://github.com/ramensoftware/windhawk-mods/discussions/47) that should add week numbers (I haven't tried it so please be cautious) thanks to [Paul](https://superuser.com/users/269897/paul) for suggesting it
- Another solution on Sourceforge would be [WeekNumber](https://sourceforge.net/projects/weeknumber/https://sourceforge.net/projects/weeknumber/). The week number can be displayed in the taskbar area. Same thing here, I haven't tried it so please be cautious.
- Use [voltura/WeekNumberLite](https://github.com/voltura/WeekNumberLite) from Github to add the week number to the taskbar area. I haven't checked it so please be cautious.

Comment: @Paul thanks, I added it

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is combination of ExplorerPatcher and Skinny Clock. Just make sure to user the Override settings.

[Skinny Clock override settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Zkb.png)

[Taskbar week number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaNGi.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1223771)

Comment: I did include my own screenshots to show the answer but StackExchange did upload the pics correctly or something (I'm getting invalid url)